# I am trying to reverse a linked list using recursion in C, I have some doubts on my recursive function

Tags: c, reverse, singly-linked-list

Below is the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *head;
struct node* reverse_ll(struct node* hnode)
{
    if(hnode == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if(hnode->next == 0)
    {
        head=hnode;
        return hnode;
    }
    struct node* ptr=reverse_ll(hnode->next);
    ptr->next=hnode;
    hnode->next=0;

 //return hnode;
}
void display()
{
    struct node *ptr;
    ptr=head;
    if(ptr==0)
    {
    printf("empty");
    }
    else
    {
        while(ptr!=0)
        {
            printf("%d->",ptr->data);
            ptr=ptr->next;

        }
          printf("null");
    }
}
int main()
{
struct node* h;    
lastinsert(1);
lastinsert(2);
lastinsert(3);
lastinsert(4);
lastinsert(5);
display();
h=reverse_ll(head);
display();
return 0;
}
```

In function reverse_ll() even if I comment "return hnode" I am getting the right output How is it possible where does ptr receives its address from when I comment "return hnode"?

output: 1->2->3->4->5->null
5->4->3->2->1->null

Comment: Please include the code for lastinsert()

Comment: Your doubts are well founded. Not returning a value and using it in the calling function provokes undefined behaviour. You use the value `ptr` in the recursive call. If the code works it is by accident. Undefined Behaviour includes behaving as intended. I suspect on your compiler the value of head happens to be on the stack and you happen to read what you want to be there without putting it there. But regardless your program has undefined behaviour and may fail on the compilers or unexpectedly if you change your code. The worst kind of UB is quiet UB more like UXB.

Comment: @Persixty have you tried runnig this code ?  Did you get the correct output ?

Comment: Hi, No. I haven't because you haven't provided runnable code because you're at least missing a definition for `lastinsert()`. I'm taking it at face value it works commenting that line out. But the way the stack is organised sometimes failing to provide a return value accidentally works anyway. 
Until you change a compiler flag or something you think unrelated and it falls apart.
We don't need to run anything to see using a return value that isn't returned is Undefined Behaviour. Just because it appears to work without it doesn't mean you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

`reverse_ll()` must return a `struct node *` in the recursive case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *head;

void lastinsert(int data) {
    struct node **c = &head;
    for(; *c; c = &(*c)->next);
    *c = malloc(sizeof(*head));
    if (!(*c)) {
        printf("malloc failed\n");
        return;
    }
    (*c)->data = data;
    (*c)->next = NULL;
}

struct node *reverse_ll(struct node* hnode) {
    if(!hnode)
        return NULL;
    if(!hnode->next) {
        head = hnode;
        return hnode;
    }
    struct node *ptr=reverse_ll(hnode->next);
    ptr->next=hnode;
    hnode->next = NULL;
    return hnode;
}

void display() {
    if(!head) {
        printf("empty");
        return;
    }
    for(struct node *ptr = head; ptr; ptr = ptr->next) {
        printf("%d->",ptr->data);
    }
    printf("null\n");
}

int main() {
    for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        lastinsert(i);
    }
    display();
    reverse_ll(head);
    display();
    // It's good practice to implement a function that frees you list
    // which you would call here.
    return 0;
}
```

and example run:

```
$ ./a.out
1->2->3->4->5->null
5->4->3->2->1->null
```